# How to downgrade Vue CLI 3.12.0 to 3.0.1

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

Need to work with Vue CLI 3.0.1, vue -version says tha my current versin is 3.12.0.

Comment: Did you try pinning a version? `npm -g install @vue/cli@3.0.1`

Comment: Thank, I was missing the middle dash -g.

Answer (score 5):

You simply need to specific the version you want to install

```
npm install -g @vue/cli@3.0.1
```

See also: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install